# Equilateral triangle in Semicircular

Tags: geometry

I have a geometry question. In this question, We have a Equilateral triangle ($ \triangle BDC$) that we draw it with one point on the circle and 2 point on the diameter. We want to prove if we draw this triangle then $OC = OD$.

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgCTY.png)

I try to prove it But I can't find any good way to prove that. It must solve with central and inscribed angles. Is it possible to help me to solve it?
I'm sorry for bad English.
Thanks.

Comment: The statement is not true if there is no restriction to the point $B$. Do you mean $B$ is the midpoint of that semicircle?

Comment: B is on semicircle But we don't know where is it. if we draw it then B is the midpoint of that semicircle but we don't know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the picture, your claim is not true. You need some other hypotheses.

[image]

Comment: thanks. It's not my question But I believe that it's question is not true.